# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout occurs even after creating a style for TabLayout

Tags: android, xml

I've tried the solution that should make it work(custom style) :

folder **res\values-v21\styles.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>
    <!-- inherit from material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used for the default value for colorControlActivated
                which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#DD4081</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

the tab layout in myFragment.xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tabs"
     style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

*using `compile 'com.android.support:design:+'`

**backtrace** from Crashlytics (Since I've migrated to Android Studio, I can't see the stacktrace there like in Eclipse. Logcat prints some things but not the actual crash excpetion) :

```
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:539)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
com.<package>.MyFragment.onCreateView (MyFragment.java:402)
android.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2220)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:973)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1148)
android.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:793)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:1535)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManager.java:482)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

and then also :

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme (ThemeUtils.java:34)
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init> (TabLayout.java:269)
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init> (TabLayout.java:263)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:619)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:764)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:835)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:838)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:838)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren (LayoutInflater.java:798)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:515)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:423)
com.<package>.MyFragment.onCreateView (MyFragment.java:402)
android.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2220)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:973)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1148)
android.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:793)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:1535)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManager.java:482)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5417)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: update your SDK,,,

Comment: it's updated(at least it says it is).
I'm using the latest android studio (2.1), latest 'android support library'(23.2.1) and 'android sdk tools'(25.1.3)

Comment: Can you also post the entire stacktrace with the exception?

Comment: @Luksprog, I've edited the post with the backtrace. (but it's what I see in Crashlytics. I have a problem since I migrated to Eclipse a week ago - unlike in Eclipse , Android Studio logcat doesn't show me the crash excpetion, it just prints system stuff)

Comment: just cut your code from folder value-v21/style to value/style and enjoy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppCompat elements (like TabLayout) check they are in an Activity with a Theme.AppCompat theme by checking if the current theme has defined the "colorPrimary" attribute. You have used the "colorPrimary" attribute from the "android" namespace, which is not the one that AppCompat uses. Add
`<item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>` (without the android namespace) to your activity's theme.

Comment: I've removed the android namespace from all(including `colorPrimaryDark` and `accent`). It doesn't crash now.
However, all I see instead of the tabs is just a small line that takes up 1/3 of the screen's width.
Also, my action bar has is colored in its corners..

Comment: Don't remove the android namespace, since it is used by other elements. You should duplicate those attributes: one with the namespace (for android api >= 21 elements) and one without the namespace (for AppCompat elements).

Comment: Thank you. 
I added a screenshot of how it looks now(edited the post).
also, I'm not sure what you meant. duplicate as in duplicate the styles.xml file that would have android namespace and the other won't?

Comment: Ok, I mean this: `<resources><style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/><item name="android:colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item><item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item></sytle></resources>`. All in the same file and style.

Comment: ok. so now It's the same result of the screenshot I just posted, except that the action bar corners are now blue and not black

Comment: I don't know. If you have "duplicated" the three colour items, I would need to see your action bar, styles, etc. When you mix AppCompat elements with native things, you must explore these elements to check that all the attributes they use are defined in your themes/styles. (Very tedious)

Comment: ok.. thanks. I'll accept the answer as it doesn't crash now, so the question/issue was fixed. (though I have other ones now..). 
Do you think I can make the transition between tabs with sliding gesture possible using TabLayout? Or would I have to use SlidingTabLayout for that?

Comment: TabLayout should do it.